# Searching for specific magic byte in an ocean of files

Tags: command-line, files

I want to know how I can search for a specific file type: I have entered a SSH server and I am trying to search for a `.jpg` file, but the owner of the server (my teacher) has removed all extensions.

I have tried `grep -lr "JFIF"` and I have found many directories with the same file name, so I jumped into a random directory which was found with the `grep` command and I tried to use the `cat` command on it, but the terminal couldn't show the entire binary.

Also the `strings` command is blocked on the ssh server, my teacher said that you have to find a jpg file and that this file contains a serial number (SN), but I have no idea where to find it.

If you guys want the SSH cardinals I will be happy to give them out to you, anyway my teacher said that you can use the `file` command to do that but I don't know how to do it.

BTW : he said (SN)

Comment: So you want help with homework?

Comment: yes please help me if you can :)

Comment: Check out the manual for file: `man file`.

Comment: We're not  a free homework service, you know . . .  But you did show some effort , which is good . . .

Comment: i am sorry, but i have tried what i know but no thing has happened, if you can help me or at least give some advice or hint i would appreciate it

Comment: @Serg - Is it possible? You don't have to answer in details just a yes or no. I am curious as I don't know but would absolutely like to find out. Thank You!

Comment: Maybe try a `find` command from the top level directory and make it run the `file` command on each file using `-exec`. This will tell you which files are JPGs. You could then examine each file with grep for the specific serial number (if you have it), or for the string SN (and hope that the number is near to it).

Comment: @Arronical what do you mean by using find with file using -exec, it's the first time i hear of this

Comment: Raphael, is it possible ? yes. Arronical has the right idea. In fact , I have an answer posted already, it's just hidden. Now should I unhide it - that's a moral problem. If I post an answer for the interested users , will that be same as doing someone's homework ?

Comment: `grep` can be used to find information within files. So if the file you want to examine is named JFIF then the command would be `grep SN /path/to/JFIF`. It may be worth using the -i option of grep, which will ignore the case of the letters.

Comment: @Arronical ok i did that, but how can i print the entire line that contains what i have searched for, because the output was `Binary file /home/ZpWdf5qj1YzD/M5KDAN44 matches`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all i want to thank @incBrain and @Serg for not answering my question directly which helped me understand a lot of new things :).

My task was finding a specific `.jpg` file that has it's extension removed, the first thing I though of is `.jpg` [magic byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) which was `JFIF`, and with @incBrain Instructions I was able to build this command

`find / -exec file {} \; | grep "JFIF"`

that line links the `find` command to `file` command using `-exec` then gets the output of both `find` & `file` commands and transfer it as an input through the pipe symbol `|` for the `grep` command which shows only the files that contain `JFIF` in their binary a.k.a `.jpg files` .

My problem actually was finding a specific serial number, at first I though that the serial number is included in the file's binary but that was wrong, then a crazy though came to my mind

> Oh! why don't I see what the picture looks like, I mean if I can't
>   find the serial number, getting the picture would be a good thing

and I have searched the Internet for a good way to transfer files from SSH into my machine and I've found this block of code which worked out!

`scp user@example.com:/home/example/file.txt /Local_Directory`

I hope that this answer helps someone in the future :).

Answer (score 12):

I'll try to give you some hints so you can solve your HW yourself.

Follow this steps:

1. read the manual of `file` by executing `man file`.
2. Then try it out by `file somefile` and see what happens
3. Try to run `file` on different file types
4. By now you should be able to understand how to find out if some file is a jpeg image or not.
5. now read the manual for `find` (or use google to find out how to use it to find all files in some directory and all subdirectories)
6. now find out how to use `-exec` option of `find` in order to connect it with previously used `file` command
7. Now you should be able to find out the filetypes of all files in needed directory and list them
8. Now read about pipes `|` and `grep` command to find out how to filter only for JPEG files.

Comment: Very good answer, teach the man to fish, without giving the fish. Upgoated. Keep doing the good job !

Comment: thank so much for your simplification, right now my only problem is to know to use `-exec` option of `find` to connect it with `file` command

Comment: @adib reading [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec) should help you.

Comment: @incBrain i have ran a code which looks like this `find / -exec file {} \; | grep "SN"` , but it ran across all files i think

Comment: i did grep "JFIF" but it is not filtering the find option

Comment: i have found many .jpg files but i don't know how to find the serial number "SN", i tried cat but it shows a lot of junk and terminal window isn't enough to show it all

Comment: there are found.jpg / image.jpg / image2.jpg / M5KMff (or something like that)    the last one isn't with .jpg so i think it's the one i want, but idk how to look for somehting inside it since strings commands is blocked on the server

Comment: well i have found the serial number, it wasn't in the image's binary, it was in the image it self. I have used `scp` to download the image and i opened it with image viewer and that was the flag!.

Comment: @adib good job! If you want you can post your solution of the HW as an answer to this question so we can up vote your effort.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, thank you so much for your instructions :) @incBrain

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be this: use `find` which recursively lists regular files (`-type f`), and performs `file` command upon each one of them. Redirect output to `grep` to filter out filetypes.

However here, I would like to do something more fun than that; more awkward , but more fun.

```
$ find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\t" -exec hexdump -n8 {} \;  | awk '/d8ff e0ff 1000 464a/{print $1}'
```

As you may or may not know every file has first 8 bytes of any file designate the filetype. Thus using `find` we search for all regular files, print it's name, but then execute hexdump to extract first 8 bytes, and let `awk` filter out only those filenames that have those first 8 bytes.

Here's a small proof:

```
$ hexdump -n 10 1450763029649.jpg               
0000000 d8ff e0ff 1000 464a 4649               
000000a

$ hexdump  -C -n 10 1450763029649.jpg           
00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46                    |......JFIF|
0000000a
```

Comment: Nice stuff by using `hexdump` +1. However I'm not sure about first 8 bytes. I did take a look into [JPEG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) standard (Annex B) and it tells that the first 2 Bytes are StartOfImage (SOI 0xFFD8) and then there are 2 Bytes frame header and 2 Bytes frame size following by the frame payload. The frame header 0xFFE0 belongs to Application data and in your case the 2 byte length of app data are 0x0010 = 16 Bytes

Comment: okay so for [JFIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) we can be sure that after SOI there will be JFIF-APP0 and the first 8 bytes of this segment (or first 10 of the file) will 100% contain JFIF string. I experimented with moving this APP segment to different location within the file and indeed `file` still recognised it as JPEG but not as JFIF

Comment: @incBrain Well, remember that `file` command works pretty much the same way - it checks first several bytes. But at the same time, when you replace APP part you are probably shifting bit sequences, so what once may have been 1010 in binary , now becomes 0101 for the sake of example. Does that image still open ?

Comment: Also , I've noticed something very interesting my CPU is little endian, so the way it reports data is low byte first. So yeah, first four bytes are `0xFFD8E0`, but look at how hexdump reports it : `d8 ff e0 d8`

Comment: So point is, that image may be damaged, but we still can know that's an image just from the first two bytes, remembering the way that data is processed also

Comment: I switched the quanitzation table block and the app data block and the image is still decodable you can try it out yourself [image](http://en.file-upload.net/download-11300298/batmanNew.jpg.html).

Comment: I was using `grep "JFIF"` from the start, but the ssh server contains a lot of .jpg files

Comment: @adib well you cannot just use `grep` on any file. Grep works best with plain-text files. Files like images are binary data, sequences of bytes, so you need different tools for that

Comment: @Serg i used `cat` but the binary was too much so the terminal didn't show it all

Answer (score 0):

```
file * | grep -i "jpeg"
```

This will search through every file in the directory and return it's file type. Via the Pipe `|` these results then get searched through by grep to find the file with the file type of "jpeg" or basically a .jpg file.