# Space-delimited file (foo.out) incorrectly read as image

Tags: libreoffice, r, file-type

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Using the command `write.table` in R, I create a space-delimited file called `foo.out`.

```
write.table(dresults, file = "foo.out", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

For some reason, Ubuntu reads it as a BMP image file (`MIME type = image/x-portable-bitmap`). This means that whenever I try to open it with something else than a text editor, for instance Libreoffice, I get an error message (`Unknown image format` or `General input/output error`).

How can I tell Ubuntu that `foo.out` (and all the other R outputs) are NOT image files?

Comment: If I have foo.txt or foo.csv then it works. If I don't have a file-type (just foo) then it still reads it as an image.
So how can I tell Ubuntu that *.out files are not images? (I know this is a different question in some sense)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of `file /path/to/foo.out`. This may help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use either `csv` or `txt` file extentions

I can't explain why it happened to you. I cannot reproduce the fact that if the output is named `foo.out` it is treated as an image file by Ubuntu. However, the workaround is to use either

```
write.table(dresults, file = "foo.csv", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

or

```
write.table(dresults, file = "foo.txt", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

In the first case, double clicking the resultant output file opens it with LebreOffice Calc (the spreadsheet application).

In the second case, double clicking the output file opens it in Gedit.

**On how to tell Ubuntu that `foo.out` is not an image**

The top answer to [Searching for specific magic byte in an ocean of files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732513/searching-for-specific-magic-byte-in-an-ocean-of-files) may help.

Hope this helps